# Set IP of two remote devices, connected by Ethernet adapter on Windows 11

Tags: windows, networking, ip, windows-11, switch

This is supposed to be trivial, but for some reason it's not. I have two devices, each with its own IP. I need to interact with both simultaneously from my Windows 11 laptop, using a switch. Each needs to have a different IPV4. The swich is linked to the computer via an Ethernet-to-USB C adapter.

**My problem is the following**: when I go to change the IP of one device in Windows, the other one will also get this IP. I will detail a bit later, let me just recap my setup first.

My setup would be this:

- laptop IP: X.0.0.3
- device 1 IP: X.0.0.10
- device 2 IP: X.0.0.11

I made a diagram below:

```
+----------+                   +----------+
| Device 1 |                   | Device 2 |
| X.0.0.10 |                   | X.0.0.11 |
+----+-----+                   +-----+----+
     |                               |
     +---------------+---------------+
                     |
                +----+-----+
                |  Switch  |   
                +-----+----+
                      |
               +------+--------+
               | USB-C adapter |
               +------+--------+
                      |
               +------+--------+
               | Windows 11 PC |
               |    X.0.0.3    |
               +---------------+
```

---

So, this is what I've tried:

- Connect only Device 1 to the computer, without the switch. No IP appears. I go to the network configuration tab in the control panel, and set its IP to X.0.0.10. But then, when I replace it with Device 2, the computer tells me Device 2 has X.0.0.10 too.
- Same with CMD. Set the IP to Device 1 to X.0.0.10 using CMD. Unplug device 1, plug device 2. Device 2 has IP X.0.0.10.
- Set Device 2 IP to X.0.0.11. Then, Device 1 gets X.0.0.11 too.
- Interact with them using the switch. Windows tells me there is only one peripheral connected, with DHCP. I can't see its IP, even with `ipconfig /all`.

**How can I obtain the configuration depicted above?**

Comment: What kind of devices? Could they both be presenting the same MAC address?

Comment: How exactly are you changing the device's address via CMD? Where does the computer tell you what address the connected device has?

Comment: @Tetsujin home-made electronics from a partner company of ours. Normally they all have their own MAC address.

Comment: @user1686 my approach was this: `netsh interface ip set address name="Eth0" static X.0.0.10 255.255.255.0`.  Eth0 is the name of my Realtek USB-to-Ethernet converter.

Comment: @C.Crt: But netsh doesn't configure the connected device at all – it configures _your_ Ethernet interface only... **your PC** becomes X.0.0.10 if you do that.

Comment: @user1686 Yeahh that's what I feared. Sorry, I'm a bit new to networking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My problem is the following: when I go to change the IP of one device in Windows, the other one will also get this IP. I will detail a bit later, let me just recap my setup first.

It's because you're not changing the IP address of the device in the first place – the only thing you're changing through `netsh` is *your own* IP address (i.e. the one assigned to the USB adapter on the Windows 11 PC).

Likewise `ipconfig` is not supposed to show any connected peripherals – it's only showing you the IP configuration of the PC itself.

> How can I obtain the configuration depicted above?

This depends entirely on how the devices were made. Ask the manufacturer.

For example, if the devices are Linux-based (like Pi-based stuff), you might be able to edit a file on the SD card. If they're more embedded (like a microcontroller), then you might need specific software from the manufacturer to send off a "set IP address" command over the network – or through a serial port (UART) – or you might need some hardware to directly write an EEPROM – or the IP address might simply be baked in during manufacture (e.g. derived from the MAC address).

The best situation is if the devices use DHCP to acquire an IP address at power-on, in which case it's simple to make your DHCP server offer a specific address to each device. (But to do that, you need to have a DHCP server first. Most off-the-shelf routers support address reservations; a Linux system running dnsmasq would also do the job.)

Comment: You're right, thanks. I got confused between the device's IP and the ethernet IP on my computer. I'll ask the manufacturer. Thank you!